# My chrome version got updated automatically to 115 version and when i run webdriver-manager update command why its downloading 114 version of chrome?

Tags: npm, selenium-chromedriver, protractor, node-modules, webdriver-manager

My chrome version got updated automatically to 115 version and when i run webdriver-manager update command why its downloading 114 version of chrome? Even i tried to download 115 version directly and paste it in webdriver manager and run webdriver-manager start command still it automatically picks 114 version exe even when that file is deleted.

Even i tried to download 115 version directly and paste it in webdriver manager and run webdriver-manager start command still it automatically picks 114 version exe even when that file is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies with the fact that Chrome-Drivers from v115, v116 and onwards, moved to [new location](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) and released in-sync with chromium.

> *Note: This works if you are using protractor & jasmine via npm*

> *The following solution should work until webdriver-manager gets updated*

1. Instead of `webdriver-manager` use `chromedriver`. Install chromedriver on your project using the following command

   `npm install chromedriver --save`
2. Update your protractor chrome initialization in  to use this binary instead of the default from webdriver-manager's location (this is important step)

   `config.chromeDriver = './node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver';`

Run your e2e tests as usual